# How to change cell color based on column index and row index from dataset?

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to change color of a cell in .xlsx file based on column index and row index that I get from variables from datasets:

I actually compare columns values with a list of columns names in a second sheet, if they match then I get column index and do the same for rows. So I need to highlight the cell in my first worksheet based on indexes.

```
public void Main()
{
 String FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::Folder_To_Be_Processed_Path"].Value.ToString();
        String File_Name = Dts.Variables["User::File_Name"].Value.ToString();
        string fileFullPath = "";
        string Error_Sheet = Dts.Variables["User::Error_Sheet_Name"].Value.ToString();
        string Data_Sheet = Dts.Variables["User::Sheet_Name"].Value.ToString();
        string ColumnErrorCellsValue;
        string RowsErrorCellsValue;
        string ColumnDataCellsValue;
        string RowsDataCellsValue;
        fileFullPath = FolderPath + "\\" + "ERR_" + File_Name;
        String strCn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
                  + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 
        12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
        //MessageBox.Show(fileFullPath);
        int RowIndex = 0;
        int ColumnIndex = 0;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Workbook excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileFullPath);
        Worksheet Data_Sheet_H = (Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets[Data_Sheet];

        string strSQLErrorColumns = "Select * From [" + Error_Sheet + 
        "AC1:AC100000]";
        string strSQLDataColumns = "Select * From [" + Data_Sheet + 
        "B1:AB1]";
        string strSQLErrorRows = "Select * From [" + Error_Sheet + 
        "A1:A100000]";
        string strSQLDataRows = "Select * From [" + Data_Sheet + 
        "A1:A100000]";
        string strSQLDataCell = "Select * From [" + Data_Sheet + 
        "B1:AB100000]";




        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(strCn);


        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapterErrorColumns = new 
        OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLErrorColumns, cn);
        DataSet dsErrorColumns = new DataSet();
        objAdapterErrorColumns.Fill(dsErrorColumns, Error_Sheet);
        System.Data.DataTable dtErrorColumns = 
        dsErrorColumns.Tables[Error_Sheet];

        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapterDataColumns = new 
        OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLDataColumns, cn);
        DataSet dsDataColumns = new DataSet();
        objAdapterDataColumns.Fill(dsDataColumns, Data_Sheet);
        System.Data.DataTable dtDataColumns = 
        dsDataColumns.Tables[Data_Sheet];

        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapterErrorRows = new 
        OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLErrorRows, cn);
        DataSet dsErrorRows = new DataSet();
        objAdapterErrorRows.Fill(dsErrorRows, Error_Sheet);
        System.Data.DataTable dtErrorRows = dsErrorRows.Tables[Error_Sheet];

        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapterDataRows = new 
        OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLDataRows, cn);
        DataSet dsDataRows = new DataSet();
        objAdapterDataRows.Fill(dsDataRows, Data_Sheet);
        System.Data.DataTable dtDataRows = dsDataRows.Tables[Data_Sheet];


        int iCntD = 0;
        int iCntE = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn ColumnData in dtDataColumns.Columns)
        {
            ColumnDataCellsValue = 
        dtDataColumns.Columns[iCntD].ColumnName.ToString();

            iCntE = 0;
            foreach (DataRow ColumnError in dtErrorColumns.Rows)
            {
                ColumnErrorCellsValue = 
        dtErrorColumns.Rows[iCntE].ItemArray[0].ToString();


                if (ColumnDataCellsValue.Equals(ColumnErrorCellsValue)) 
        ColumnIndex = 
        ColumnData.Table.Columns[ColumnDataCellsValue].Ordinal;



                iCntE = iCntE + 1;
           }

            iCntD = iCntD + 1;

       }

        int jCntD = 0;
        int jCntE = 0;
        foreach (DataRow rowDataID in dtDataRows.Rows)
        {               
            RowsDataCellsValue = 
        dtDataRows.Rows[jCntD].ItemArray[0].ToString();

            iCntE = 0;
            foreach (DataRow rowErrorID in dtErrorRows.Rows)
            {              

                RowsErrorCellsValue = 
        dtErrorRows.Rows[jCntE].ItemArray[0].ToString();


                if (RowsDataCellsValue.Equals(RowsErrorCellsValue)) RowIndex 
        = dtDataRows.Rows.IndexOf(rowDataID);


                iCntE = iCntE + 1;   
            }
                iCntD = iCntD + 1;

        }


       ((Range)Data_Sheet_H.Cells[RowIndex, ColumnIndex]).Interior.Color = 
       ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);

        excelBook.Save();
        excelBook.Close();
        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The excel worksheet uses indexes starting at 1 while a DataTable indexes starts at zero.  So you have to offset the location by one.  A dataset does not have color and oledb doesn't have color.  To change color of a worksheet you need to use the Excel Interop interface.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you so much for your answer. I've adapted my code accordingly, and I've put the whole code to give you more visibility on how I'm processing. I actually define the dataset by query, then I get column index and row index dinameclly when I've added : `Worksheet Data_Sheet_H = (Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets[Data_Sheet];` my code can't be compiled anymore and I don't see the error. FYI : I'm using a script task in SSIS package. Thank you upfront for your help.

Comment: There is Worksheet, Worksheets, Sheet, Sheets.  Make sure you are using the correct one.  A worksheet is the standard excel sheet.  A Sheet can be a worksheet , as well as other types like a Graph or Picture.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your answer, but I've added a new objet `Worksheet` that I called `Data_Sheet_H` which is in my `Workbook` called `excelBoox` and the name of the worksheet I get it from variable string `Data_Sheet` I really don't see where the error is coming from. Can you have a look to my code please ? especailly this part : `Worksheet Data_Sheet_H = (Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets[Data_Sheet];` and `((Range)Data_Sheet_H.Cells[RowIndex, ColumnIndex]).Interior.Color = 
ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);`

Comment: What value is returned from : string Data_Sheet = Dts.Variables["User::Sheet_Name"].Value.ToString();  It needs to be a sheet name (string).

Comment: Yes it is, it contains sheet name that needs to be handled. and it works in the query `string strSQLDataColumns = "Select * From [" + Data_Sheet + "B1:AB1]";` and to make it easy the script works fine because I when I show the value of the cell with variables RowIndex and ColumnIndex the MassageBox shows the correct value. The part that is not working is to highlight this cell. I'm very thankful for your help.

Comment: I usulaly get it working in VBA and then translate. Do you need Color or ColorIndex?  I do not know what the color translator returns.

Comment: I'm little bit familiar with C# but more than VBA :(. I need to change the text color to red please. So Color will be easier.

Comment: Red is .Font.Color = 255.

Comment: @jdweng I'm still getting error in `Worksheet Data_Sheet_H = (Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets[Data_Sheet];`

Comment: Try var instead of Worksheet.  Don't cast.

Comment: @jdweng I put this : `var Data_Sheet_H = (Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets[Data_Sheet];` but still the same with no error message.

Comment: Is the text in the cell?  You will not see any FONT Color without text.

Comment: @jdweng actually the script can not be validated by the script task. when I close the script task I have an error window telling me that there are errors in my compilation, but without showing the error message. when I put this ligne in comment the error window disappears. Which means that there is an error in this `var Data_Sheet_H = (Worksheet)excelBook.Sheets[Data_Sheet];` and it's the same when I change `var` by `Worksheet`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sheets is an array which you can index by either name or number.  The type returned is Worksheet.  So there is no reason to add the cast.  So either excel is null or the Data_Sheet is not valid (or null).  Also an invalid sheet name could give the error..

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean by adding the cast ? Even when I index by number for Sheets it gaves the same and my excel is not null because when I put the cell value in massage box it shows the correct value that I have in this cell : `object CellToHigh = dsDataCell.Tables[Data_Sheet].Rows[RowIndex][ColumnIndex];MessageBox.Show(CellToHigh.ToString());` I get YYYYY this is what I've put in the cell.

Comment: First there is a mapping between the dsDataCell.Tables name and the worksheet name.  The may not be the same.  I would get the sheetname use following : string name = excelBook.Sheets[1].Name

Comment: @jdweng when I added the ligne `string name = excelBook.Sheets[1].Name;` I got again the error windwo Scripts contained in the package have compliation errors.

Comment: Even when I replaced `Sheets` by `Worksheets`

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the excelBook object.  The interop library has top match the version of excel installed on your PC.  Make sure excelBook is not null.

Comment: @jdweng I agree with you there is somthing wrong with the excelBook object because it's the only line causing issue and excelBook is not null, because by adding this : `string excelname = excelBook.Name;` the message box shows correct file name that I'm handling. What can be wrong with excelBook object ?

Comment: As I said the version of Interop is not the same

Comment: @jdweng I've made some DLL's updates and finally this statement worked for me :`Worksheet xlSheets = excelBook.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;`. I'm verry thankful for your precious help and support.